# Custom block for contact form

Tags: hooks

I have created contact us block ,inside that i have add the html form with form action action="/foldername/contact/". on submit its redirecting to contact page . how to submit the form with out redirecting to contact us page

Comment: Why don't you use Form API form or one of the ready contrib modules?

Answer (score 0):

That's how the `action` attribute works, it submits the data in the form (via POST or GET) to the location you specify. You should, as Molot says, use the Form API. Or even easier, the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module (in Drupal 7), which allows you to create a webform as a block. Install the module and then

1. Create your webform in a node.
2. Edit the node.
3. Select the Webform tab.
4. Select the Forms settings tab.
5. Select Advanced settings.
6. Switch on Available as block.
7. Save configuration.

If you have a Drupal 6 site, you can use [Webform Block](https://drupal.org/project/webformblock).